# Is there a name for a bunch of features under each other?

Tags: website-design, terminology

I know this isn't particularly the most intelligent or specific question ever, but I can't really say more than: what's this called?

Basically a bunch of features (often for a product) under each other...

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: What do you mean "under each other"?

Comment: @tohster Like... the screenshot.

Comment: William, the screenshot is ambiguous.  Do you mean the 2nd row of features under the first row?  Or the screenshot has 6 features which are a subgroup of a larger set of features? Or the descriptive text which appears under the feature title?  It's unclear whether you are asking a layout, semantic, terminology, or UI element question!

Comment: @tohster I'm aware, I really don't know how to ask this. the name I need to know is of the whole thing.

Comment: Surprised that this was upvoted, it's an incredibly bad question.

Comment: I've usually seen them grouped under "Features" or "What we offer"

Answer (score 1):

"Feature set" is the term I'm familiar with for features on a single product.

If they are discrete items grouped together, you can call it a "bundle" or "product package".